# Create typings dynamically from object

Tags: typescript, dynamic-typing, conditional-types

Say I have the following two types:

```
export type CollectionNames = 'twitter:tweets' | 'twitter:users' | 'twitter:metadata-cashtag'

export type CollectionType<T extends CollectionNames> = 
    T extends 'twitter:tweets' ? Tweet :
    T extends 'twitter:users' ? User :
    T extends 'twitter:metadata-cashtag' ? CashtagMetadataDb :
    never
```

I feel this is very clunky and I'm not very keen on having the strings twice. Also it's possible to legally misspell them in the latter type.

Is there any way to create these dynamically from an object such as this:

```
typings = {
    'twitter:tweets': Tweet,
    'twitter:users': User,
    'twitters:metadata-cashtag': CashtagMetadataDb
}
```

The idea is that multiple modules will have their own `CollectionType` type which is then aggregated into one `CollectionType` in the importing root module. So if I have two modules `Coin` and `Twitter` imported using `* as`, it looks something like this:

```
type CollectionName = Twitter.CollectionNames | Coin.CollectionNames

type CollectionType<T extends CollectionName> = 
    T extends Twitter.CollectionNames ? Twitter.CollectionType<T> :
    T extends Coin.CollectionNames ? Coin.CollectionType<T> :
    never
```

These will then be used in a function like so where the types are of the latter kind (`Collection` here is from MongoDB):

```
async function getCollection<T extends CollectionName> (name: T): Promise<Collection<CollectionType<T>>>
```

Comment: Can you please post an example how `CollectionType` is used?

Comment: Updated the question with edits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in this case you don't need conditional types at all; you can do this with [`keyof` and lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) instead.  You probably *could* create an object like `typings` and derive a type from it, but unless you need that object for something at runtime (and have objects of type `Tweet`, `User`, etc lying around) I'd say you should just make an interface type like this:

```
export interface Collections {
  'twitter:tweets': Tweet,
  'twitter:users': User,
  'twitter:metadata-cashtag': CashtagMetadataDb
}
```

Then, your `CollectionNames` and `CollectionType` types can be defined in terms of that type:

```
export type CollectionNames = keyof Collections;
export type CollectionType<K extends CollectionNames> = Collections[K];
```

You can verify that the above types act the same as your definitions.  In the case that you have multiple modules that have exported `Collections` types, you can simply merge them using interface extension and re-derive `CollectionNames` and `CollectionType` from it:

```
export interface Collections extends Twitter.Collections, Coin.Collections {}
export type CollectionNames = keyof Collections;
export type CollectionType<K extends CollectionNames> = Collections[K];
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: This is fantastic and fits what I need perfectly! Thank you for your time :)