# Confusing Typescript Generic Typing Error

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm really confused here. This is also an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092690/create-typings-dynamically-from-object) if you need any extra detail.

This is my code:

```
interface Collections extends Twitter.Collections, Coin.Collections {}
type CollectionName = keyof Collections
type CollectionType <T extends CollectionName> = Collections[T]

const _collections: {
    [K in CollectionName]?: Collection<CollectionType<K>>
} = {}

export async function getCollection<T extends CollectionName> (name: T): Promise<Collection<CollectionType<T>>> {
    if (name in _collections && typeof _collections[name] !== 'undefined') {
        return _collections[name]
    }

    ...
}
```

It's on this last `if` line that the following ts error displays:

```
Type '{ "twitter:tweets"?: Collection<Tweet> | undefined; "twitter:users"?: Collection<User> | undefined; "twitter:metadata-cashtag"?: Collection<CashtagMetadataDb> | undefined; "coins:all"?: Collection<...> | undefined; }[T]' is not assignable to type 'Collection<Collections[T]>'.
    Type 'Collection<Tweet> | Collection<User> | Collection<CashtagMetadataDb> | Collection<Coin> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Collection<Collections[T]>'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Collection<Collections[T]>'.
```

As you can see, I've tried my best to type check here but I'm unable to get this to work.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The code provided is not enough to reproduce the error. But I think it's related to `[K in CollectionName]?` being optional.

It could be fixed using definite assertions `return _collections[name]!` (note the exclamation mark), but again I'm not sure since the code provided is not enough

Comment: And I don't know if you're returning the correct type after the `if` clause. So this could be another error

Comment: When I remove the `?` in `[K in CollectionName]?` that error goes away but I can't fill the object on declaration. I'll have to use the bang, `!`, which I never knew about before. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Automatic narrowing doesn't work on element access expressions like `_collections[name]`.  If you want to take advantage of narrowing, you'll have to save the value in a local variable before testing it.  And due to limitations on how TypeScript reasons about lookup types, you'll need a type annotation on that local variable.  This should work:

```
export async function getCollection<T extends CollectionName>(name: T): Promise<Collection<CollectionType<T>>> {
    let coll: Collection<CollectionType<T>> | undefined = _collections[name];
    if (coll !== undefined) {
        return coll
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please collect the complete code to reproduce the error in the question so I can debug?